# How to add content recursively to an array?

Tags: php

I have a file with multiple lines, I need to iterate each line and save it into an array.   Actually this is my code:

```
while(($line = fgets($fh)) !== false)
{
      $obj = json_decode($line);

      $content['trace']= array(
             'message' => $obj->trace->details->{"[message]"},
      );

}
```

Now If I have for example two lines:

> Line 1
>
> Line 2

In the `$content` array returned after the end of the while I can see only the content of Line2. Should I use `array_push()` or there is something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want the resulting array to look like.  To build a message array:

```
$content['trace']['message'][] = $obj->trace->details->message;
```

Or to build multiple arrays each with a message key:

```
$content['trace'][]['message'] = $obj->trace->details->message;
```